# jQuery mobile popup not appearing in center

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile and trying to show jQuery pop on page load. But when the page is loaded popup is not appearing in center, instead popup's TOP LEFT corner is appearing in center.

But as soon as browser window size gets change popup automatically shifts to center (Even if I press F12 for developers tool). And then all frequent calls to $('#popupBasic').popup("open"); make it to appear in center of the screen.

But first time top left corner of the popup box appearing in center.

Comment: I am having a problem similar to this one. Sometimes it appears as you state above, but most of the times the popup don't even appear visible (although it is there - as I can see by examining the DOM). Not sure what the solution is.

Comment: having the exact same problem with 1.3.0 as well. Latest version of chrome. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 13):

try this: data-position-to="window".

[this is the source](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/)

Answer (score 11):

You may try repositioning the popup on pageshow:

```
$( '#popupLogin' ).popup( 'reposition', 'positionTo: window' );
```

I reckon what you are experiencing is down to the positioning happening prior the page is fully drawn by the browser. You can overcome this by repositioning the popup like this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '.selector', function(){
  $('#popupBasic').popup('reposition', 'positionTo: window');
});
```

Comment: I use one popup div, which is used to display different images based upon user selection. these images are of different sizes, which are not known until loaded. calling this: `$( '#popupLogin' ).popup( 'reposition', 'positionTo: window' );` after an image is loaded into the popup successfully centers the popup.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on("popupafteropen", function() {
    $('#popup').popup('reposition', 'positionTo: window');
});
```

You can use the custom pop up events to reposition it after opening

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. You only want to show the popup after the page has been painted.

Adding your code to listen to the pageshow event instead of the pageinit event will probably fix your problem. It fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question.

A few items you should provide:

- What browser are you testing on and what version?
- What version of JQM?
- Are there any custom CSS interacting with JQM?

As of JQM 1.2, Popup options available:

default: "origin"

Sets the element relative to which the popup will be centered. It has the following values:

"origin" When the popup opens, center over the coordinates passed to the open() call (see methods page).

"window" When the popup opens, center in the window.

jQuery selector When the popup opens, create a jQuery object based on the selector, and center over it. The selector is filtered for elements that are visible with ":visible". If the result is empty, the popup will be centered in the window.

[Source](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/#/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/options.html)

Comment: It is appearing in almost every where I have tried, 
Chrome Version 24.0.1312.32 beta-m
Firefox 16.0.1
HTC Wildfire 2.2.1

JQM jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

No Custom CSS with JQM

I have tried the all popup options, but still no success.

To replication you can try this
`<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-history="false" data-transition="flow" class="ui-content">SOME LONG CONTENT</div>`

and then 
`$(document).bind('pageinit', function({
    $('#popupBasic').popup("open");
});`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I set the width of popup `div` manually; try:

```
$("#popupBasic").css("width","200px");
```